# What is the difference between 'passport', 'passport-local' and 'passport-jwt'?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local, passport-jwt

I am trying to learn NodeJS and saw these three functions/classes in a tutorial but couldn't understand what they are and when should we use which one?

Do I need to use both passport-local and passport-jwt at the same time or only one of them?

Answer (score 15):

[Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) is nodejs 'Connect style middleware' for user authentication. You're most likely to see it as [Express](https://expressjs.com) middleware. To use passport you need to use `passport` and a 'strategy' defining what you are using to authenticate against. This could for example be Facebook or Google via oauth, SAML, or simply cookies. So to use Passport you need to `require` both the `passport` module itself *and* the relevant 'strategy' module.

To use a 'strategy' you use the strategy constructor to **configure** `passport`. The 'local' example given in the docs is slightly obtuse when you first come across `passport`, so using the [Google example](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/) may make it a little easier to understand:

```js
var passport = require('passport'); // passport
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy; // Youa also need to import the Google 'strategy'

// configure passport to use the Google strategy by passing the GoogleStrategy constructor to passport.use()
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         return done(err, user);
       });
  }
));

// now you can use passport.authenticate() with the google strategy
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

// GET /auth/google/callback which Google send your user to after they authenticate using Oauth
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

[`passport-local`](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) is the strategy you would use if you are authenticating against a **username and password** stored 'locally' i.e. in the database of your app - 'local' means local to your application server, not local to the end user.

[`passport-jwt`](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/) is the strategy for using **JSON Web Tokens**.

Comment: Where should we use which of them?

Comment: You would use `passport` if you want a system for logging users in securely to a web app running on nodejs - usually that is likely to be an [express](https://expressjs.com) app. You always need `passport` **plus** _one_ of the others, depending on how you want to authenticate your users and whether you want to store their credentials. As @divyani says in the other answer, JWT would usually be for an API endpoint

Answer (score 9):

**passport** Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js.Passport uses the concept of strategies to authenticate requests. Strategies can range from verifying username and password credentials, delegated authentication using OAuth (for example, via Facebook or Twitter), or federated authentication using OpenID.

**passport-local** The local authentication strategy authenticates users using a username and password. The strategy requires a verify callback, which accepts these credentials and calls done providing a user.

**passport-jwt** This module lets you authenticate endpoints using a JSON web token. It is intended to be used to secure RESTful endpoints without sessions.

Comment: Where should we use which of them?

Comment: So passport-jwt can be used for secure RESTful endpoints without sessions and passport-local can be used to authenticate using a username and password in any Node.js applications.

Comment: passport-jwt:   var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = 'secret';
opts.issuer = 'accounts.examplesoft.com';
opts.audience = 'yoursite.net';
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));

Comment: passport-local: passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

Answer (score 1):

It can be understood that `passport` is a basic package

- `passport local` uses local storage authentication. After successful login, use `session` and `cookie` to maintain login status
- `passport jwt` uses`jwt`authentication, which is applicable to the`api`interface, and uses `token` `Authorization` and other request headers to maintain login status